# use ng-repeat to display mongoose queries

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I want to use angular to show the array I get from mongoose.find(). My approach

controller:

```
requests:function(req,res){
        corporate.find({request:false},function(err,corp){
            if(corp){
                console.log("yes");
                res.render('requests',{corp});
            }
        });
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" ng-app = "">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Business Requests</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
<div ng-init = <%="bus=corp"%>>
    <p ng-repeat = "c in bus">
        Name: {{c.name}} <br>
        Email: {{c.email}}<br>
        type: {{c.type}}<br>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

it shows just nothing at all but the header hello

Comment: you are missing some key components for angular.  you don't have an app or controller, and both are required.

Comment: `ng-init` is not intended for what you are using it for either

Comment: maybe you should try creating the jsfiddle first and make sure the app loads without any errors.

Comment: What should I use instead of  ng-init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is to do the mongoose query in the controller for example:

```
request: function(req,res){
    corporate.find({request:true},function(corp){
      if(corp){
        res.json({success: true, corporate: corp});
      }else{
        res.json({success: false});
       }
   }
}
```

Then you use $http.get() to get the query from the callback of json success and you put that value in a scope and ng repeat it in the html